# Using pg_dump with no owner information still outputting role information

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I dumped a database using `pg_dump -O -x` expecting all ownership and role information to be ignored, however, it is still including specific mentions to manager roles in the original database which are failing to be imported because they don't exist in the new database which I'm importing into. See the snippet of the dump.sql file:

```
--
-- Name: reassign_owned(); Type: FUNCTION; Schema: public; Owner: -
--

CREATE FUNCTION reassign_owned() RETURNS event_trigger
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
    AS $$
        begin
                -- do not execute if member of rds_superuser
                IF EXISTS (select 1 from pg_catalog.pg_roles where rolname = 'rds_superuser')
                AND pg_has_role(current_user, 'rds_superuser', 'member') THEN
                        RETURN;
                END IF;

                -- do not execute if not member of manager role
                IF NOT pg_has_role(current_user, 'rdsbroker_xxxxx_manager', 'member') THEN
                        RETURN;
                END IF;

                -- do not execute if superuser
                IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM pg_user WHERE usename = current_user and usesuper = true) THEN
                        RETURN;
                END IF;

                EXECUTE 'reassign owned by "' || current_user || '" to "rdsbroker_xxxxx_manager"';
        end
        $$;
```

Comment: Do you run pg_dump in plain-text format ?
Do you use -O for pg_dump and/or pg_restore ?

Comment: It's dumped as a plain text file and the restoration is *not* using pg_restore. Currently that's my only choice.

Comment: Is this an AWS RDS instance ? It looks like an AWS specific feature.

Comment: It is indeed an AWS RDS instance, I'm not sure there's any configuration for disabling this.

Answer (score 3):

`-O` means that pg_dump itself does not emit ownership information.  It doesn't cause it to edit the source code of any functions it might dump, in an attempt to prevent those functions from doing what they were written to do.

Comment: @kalpaitch This answer explains the effect described in the question and should thus be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a quick search in pg_dump and pg_restore source code and I see no usage of REASSIGN OWNED statement.